# How do I get the most out of a Science officer in Star Trek Online?

Tags: star-trek-online

I created a science officer, and I got to Lieutenant Commander, but I spent all my upgrades on weapons and ships.  I think I'm doing it wrong.

What should I be trying to focus on with a science officer?  What role should I be playing in combat in single-player missions?  Should I be getting security officers as my crew and be in a support role to them when doing ground combat missions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since I played so this may be outdated. In most cases, you'll want to try and even out your points across most skills. Maxing out your skills should only be done when you want the extra ability that some skills give you. Generally, I play science officers as a support/debuff space character. I usually focus on shield drains, tractor beams, and "healing" powers.

When on ground missions, I focus on setting up expose/exploit attacks. My ground crew is usually a mix of Tactical, Science, and Engineering officers. What you want to do is to find powers and abilities that mesh with your play style.

Hope that helps.